How can I change the desktop background on Windows using a script?
On X Windows I had a cool 'silent-alarm" reminder script that would change my root window (background) color to solid red, just for a few seconds a few moments before changing it back. Is there a way to do this for Windows XP?
I'm thinking some kind of scheduled task that uses cscript to set registry keys (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop) . However my attempts don't seem to have any effect. What do I have to signal to read those registry entries and re-draw the desktop?

It may be easier to program something that creates a solid window with bottom most property set and use that. It will temporarily remove your desktop icons too, but it is going to be easier, and will work on all versions of windows.
